# How can i solve internal error: Huge input lookup

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I receive this error when i try to expand an xml file: internal error: Huge input lookup

this is the code:

```
private function get_product_xml( \XMLReader $reader ) {
        $doc = new \DOMDocument( '1.0', 'UTF-8' );
        $xml = simplexml_import_dom( $doc->importNode( $reader->expand(), true ));

        return $xml;
    }

    /**
     * @param \SimpleXMLElement $product_xml
     * @param bool $check_imported
     * @param string $lang
     *
     * @return array|bool
     */
    private function populate_product( \SimpleXMLElement $product_xml, $check_imported = true, $lang = 'default' ) {
        $sku       = (string) $product_xml->code;
        $remote_id = (int) $product_xml->id;

        $tags = Tools::populate_tags( $product_xml->tags->tag );

        $conversion = isset( $this->settings['conversion'] ) ? $this->settings['conversion'] : 1;
        $api_url    = isset( $this->settings['api-url'] ) ? $this->settings['api-url'] : '';
        
        $only_name = ( array_key_exists('remove-brand-from-title', $this->settings) && (boolean) $this->settings['remove-brand-from-title'] );
        $name         = Tools::get_product_name( $tags, $product_xml, $lang, $only_name );
        $price        = Tools::calculate_price( (float) $product_xml->bestTaxable, (float) $product_xml->taxable, (float) $product_xml->streetPrice, (float) $product_xml->suggestedPrice );
        $best_taxable = ( (float) $product_xml->bestTaxable ) * $conversion;
        $taxable      = ( (float) $product_xml->taxable ) * $conversion;
        $street_price = ( (float) $product_xml->streetPrice ) * $conversion;
        $suggested_price = ( (float) $product_xml->suggestedPrice ) * $conversion;
        $availability = (int) $product_xml->availability;
        $image_url    = $api_url . $product_xml->pictures->image->url;
```

It's a catalog and the plugin should expand this xml file to import products in wordpress.